# Merge Sort of 2 arrays into a third array in C

Tags: c, mergesort

I am writing a function in order to sort 2 arrays into a 3rd array using a merge sort in **O(n)** but I am getting some compiling errors. Any help would be appreciated or even a possible solution!

> *Write a C function to merge 2 arrays, assumed to be ordered by ascending values, and store the result in a 3rd array, so it in turn is ordered.*

```c
#define LEN1    4
#define LEN2    5
    
int *merge(const int[], int, const int[], int); //allocates and returns an arrray
    
int main() {
    int a[LEN1] = { 1, 2, 3, 8 };
    int b[LEN2] = { -1, 2, 4, 7, 11 };
    int *m;   // to hold pointer to merged array, should free
    int *mp;  // point to successive result elements
    
    m = merge(a, LEN1, b, LEN2);
    mp = m;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN1 + LEN2; i++)
        printf ("/%d", *mp++);
    free(m);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My section of code follows :

```
int c[LEN1+LEN2];
int *merge(const int a[], int alen, const int b[], int blen)
a=malloc(sizeof(int)*alen);
b=malloc(sizeof(int)*blen);
c=malloc(sizeof(int)*alen+blen);
{
    int i,j,k;
    i = j = k = 0;
    for(i=0;i < alen && j < blen;)
        {
            if(a[i] < b[j])
                {
                    c[k] = a[i];
                    k++;
                    i++;
                }
            else
                {
                    c[k] = b[j];
                    k++;
                    j++;
                }
        }
    while(i < alen)
    {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
while(j < blen)
    {
        c[k] = b[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

I also apologize for the code not being commented, I don't have much experience in C.

Comment: There are many basic mistakes in the code that you show. It seem you don't really understand how functions and function arguments works. Please take a few step back and refresh it in your text books.

Comment: There's also some other things that stand out, like for example the `main` function variable `mp`, which isn't needed. You can just use `m[i]` inside the output loop.

Comment: Please add the compiling errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted, the code is broken:

- Extra code is written outside the body of the function, which is enclosed in a block after the prototype.  This does not compile.
- `a` and `b` are function arguments, do not allocate memory for them and overwrite their values. Declaring them in the function prototype as pointers to `int` would be equivalent but much less confusing as the arrays are passed to the `merge` function as such: `main()` passes arrays `a` and `b` to `merge` but arrays are passed as a pointer to their first element in C so the function just receives pointers. This process is described as *arrays decay into pointers*. The function arguments happen to bear the same name as the arrays in `main`, another source of confusion.
- `c` should be declared inside the body as a pointer to `int` and initialized with the address returned by a call to `malloc()` with the size of the combined array. `+` has a lesser precedence than `*` so `alen + blen` must be parenthesized for proper computation:

  ```
    int *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * (alen + blen));
  ```
- the `merge` function must return the pointer to the allocated array with `return c;`
- testing for allocation failure is also advisable.

Also work on your presentation to help readability:

- indent the code properly
- use spaces wisely: around binary operators and after `,`

Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // for malloc and free

#define LEN1    4
#define LEN2    5
    
// allocates an array and returns a pointer to be freed
int *merge(const int[], int, const int[], int);
    
int main() {
    int a[LEN1] = { 1, 2, 3, 8 };
    int b[LEN2] = { -1, 2, 4, 7, 11 };
    int *m = merge(a, LEN1, b, LEN2);

    if (m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < LEN1 + LEN2; i++)
            printf ("/%d", m[i]);
        printf("\n");
        free(m);
    }
    return 0;
}

int *merge(const int *a, int alen, const int *b, int blen) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * (alen + blen));
    if (c == NULL)
        return NULL;

    i = j = k = 0;
    while (i < alen && j < blen) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        } else {
            c[k] = b[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while (i < alen) {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < blen) {
        c[k] = b[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you allocating memory to `a` and `b`? and why are they outside the scope of the function. By seeing the code, I strongly suggest you to please learn the basic syntax of the language properly. `C` should not be defined globally.
I have changed the following in the code.
i) removed memory allocation of `a` and `b`.
ii) Initialization of `c` in the scope of the function.
iii) returned the pointer `c` from the function.
The code is now working fine.

```
int* merge (const int a[], int alen, const int b[], int blen)
{
   int *c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(alen+blen));
   int i,j,k;
   i = j = k = 0;
   for(i=0;i < alen && j < blen;)
   {
        if(a[i] < b[j])
        {
            c[k] = a[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            c[k] = b[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
   }
   while(i < alen)
   {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
   }
   while(j < blen)
   {
        c[k] = b[j];
        k++;
        j++;
   }
   return c;
}
```